# Mounting truecrypt fails with "Error: device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument " 

Tags: 11.10, truecrypt

I've been using truecrypt for several years now. Today I upgraded to 11.10 and mounting with truecrypt failed with this message:

```
Error: device-mapper: reload ioctl failed: Invalid argument
```

On some googling I found that this could be a problem if the Kernel is not compiled with XTS support and the solution was to use "-m=nokernelcrypto" option. This works for me but this is less than ideal since there will be a performance hit.

Can anyone tell me how to get the stock 7.1 version of Truecrypt to work on Ubuntu 11.10 natively, seems like this should be a major issue if Truecrypt support was pulled from Ubuntu.

Comment: This guy had to use AES only on his RPi in order to not have to do that: https://chewett.co.uk/blog/433/veracrypt-error-device-mapper-reload-ioctl-error-fixed/ Seems to be related to what algorithms the O.S. supports. Also I think the disk format you use makes a difference as well (e.g. NTFS FAT etc.). Same goes for VeraCrypt.

Answer (score 1):

XTS (if anyone is wondering) is a mode of operation that allows you to use the block cipher repeatedly with a single key. It's currently the default in TrueCrypt.

I'm using kernal 3.0.0-12-generic in 11.10 (64-bit) and as far as I can tell TrueCrypt (7.1) is using XTS on my install. (according to the volume property page)

Also - I don't think Ubuntu ever supported TrueCrypt directly in the first place - it's not available through the Ubuntu Software Center and Unity ignores the application's notification icon which is critical for novice users (if they close the main TrueCrypt window). Bug 109701 (on launchpad) also suggests that licensing may be preventing better support commitment.